# Undable to retain drop down selection while doing post

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have one asp.net MVC application where I am adding model with dropdown list. But while posting the data back to server and reloading the page , drop down selection is not retained. I have even tried with ViewBag.
     Attaching code snapshot.

```
view code :
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFiles", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="row">
        <section>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>Countries</h2>
                <div>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.countries, new SelectList(ViewBag.CountryList, "CountryId", "CountryName"), "Select Country", new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>

@model PortalModel.ViewModel : model having all the data
```

Comment: please read this post i hope it gives you an idea to solve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540793/how-to-set-default-selected-value-for-html-dropdownlistfor

Comment: Can you also share the relevant code part from your controller? Then, we could see what is happening there.